# VK API, groups.getMembers

Tags: javascript, vkontakte-api, api, http

Делаю запрос как указано здесь - https://dev.vk.com/method/groups.getMembers

Запрос: `https://api.vk.com/method/groups.getMembers?group_id=185052202&access_token=TOKEN&v=5.131`

Получаю объект с 1000 пользователей

Теперь хочу получать и пол пользователей - указываю параметр **fields=sex**

Делаю запрос: `https://api.vk.com/method/groups.getMembers?group_id=185052202&fields=sex&access_token=TOKEN&v=5.131`

И в результате при использовании параметра **fields** получаю меньше 1000 пользователей, в разных группах по разному. Как получать объект со всеми пользователями используя параметр **fields** ?

Answer (score 1):

Метод `getMembers` не возвращает дополнительные поля для заблокированных аккаунтов. При этом заблокированные пользователи всё ещё числятся участниками группы и возвращаются в общем списке